# Aligning of elements in CSS dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

How do I make one section of the CSS secondary drop down menu drop to the left instead of the right?

In regards to the second drop down, I would like the secondary drop down to move to the left instead of the right.  I've tried several different ways with no luck.  here is the code.

Thanks for your help! :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style>

/* Update the font type and size here */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:15px;
}

/*Update the main horizontal background color here - it is currently NCR green */
    #main_nav ul {
        background: #54B948;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transition: .5s;
        transition: .5s;
    }
/*Update the width of the individual navigation here */ 
    #main_nav li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 220px;
        list-style: none;
        -webkit-transition: .5s;
        transition: .5s;
    }

    #main_nav > ul > li > a{
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
/*Update the color of the font here */  
    #main_nav a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 5px 15px;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    #main_nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    #main_nav ul ul ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    #main_nav li:hover, #main_nav li:hover li {
        background: #ddd;
    }
/*1st menu dropdown */  
    #main_nav ul li.menu_1 ul.drop_1 li:hover {
        background: #E14F3C;
    }
    #main_nav ul li.menu_1:hover {
        background: #E14F3C;
    }

    #main_nav ul li.menu_1 ul.drop_1 li{
        background: #b12614;
    }
/* END 1st menu dropdown */ 

/*2nd menu dropdown */  

    #main_nav ul li.menu_2 ul.drop_2 li:hover {
        background: #8080D9;
    }

    #main_nav ul li.menu_2:hover {
        background: #8080D9;
    }

    #main_nav ul li.menu_2 ul.drop_2 li{
        background: #3435c2;
    }
/*END 2nd menu dropdown */

/*3rd menu dropdown */  
    #main_nav ul li.menu_3:hover {
        background:#F4A725;
    }
/*4th menu dropdown */  
    #main_nav ul li.menu_4:hover {
        background:#5CD8EE;
    }
/*END 4th menu dropdown */

    #main_nav li li:hover, #main_nav li li:hover li {
        background: #bbb;
    }

    #main_nav li li li:hover {
        background: #999;
    }

    #main_nav li:hover > ul {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    }


</style>
</head>

<body>
<nav id="main_nav">
<ul>
    <li class="menu_1">
        <a href="">Executes: Grades 6-10</a>
        <ul class="drop_1">
            <li><a href="">Core Competencies</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Customer Dedication</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Drive for Results</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Innovation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Problem Solving</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Teamwork</a></li>
                  </ul>
             </li>
              <li><a href="">Optional Leadership Competencies</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Continuous Learning</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Managing Vision & Purpose</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Organizational Agility</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Global Business Knowledge</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Courage in Mgt & Conflict</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Perspective</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Priority Setting</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu_2">
        <a href="">Guides: Grades 11-14</a>
        <ul class="drop_2">
        <li>
            <a href="">Core Competencies</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Customer Dedication</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Drive for Results</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Innovation</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Problem Solving</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Teamwork</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Required Leadership Competencies</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Perspective</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Priority Setting</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Optional Leadership Competencies</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Continuous Learning</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Managing Vision & Purpose</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Organizational Agility</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Global Business Knowledge</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Courage in Mgt & Conflict</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul> 
         <li class="menu_3">
                <a href="">Shapes: Grade 15</a>
         </li>
         <li  class="menu_4">
                <a href="">Inspires: Grades 16+</a>
         </li>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish a menu to open to the left then the `right` must be at 0. So instead of having `left: 0` or `left: 100%` change that to `right: 0` and if you need to overwrite the left positioning you can also add `left:auto`

If this is your second menu here's an updated code

```
 #main_nav ul ul {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 100%;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
```